# Publish Shiny app using R studio connect

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I am trying to push a shiny app on  a machine which has restricted access to the internet. So we just got the CRAN whitelisted but cant whitelist GitHub.

I had a couple of packages on GitHub which now I have compressed as tar.gz file. Now when I still try to publish the app I get the error saying my package was not found in CRAN which is true. So how can I publish this app with my package compressed already on that machine?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your 'Server.SourcePackageDir'
see below the link of Rstudio connect documentation : https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/226871467-Package-management-in-RStudio-Connect